# How to pass random particular value in loadrunner..?

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

I have 10 values I want pick values randomly but 2nd position value Hyderabad next time Hyderabad value position 5th position how to capture Hyderabad value in loadrunner?

Answer (score 0):

> ...how to capture Hyderabad value in loadrunner?

Capture is a question of correlation.  This will likely be a manual correlation effort